# Apply skin to all JavaFX child controls

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am implementing some JavaFX controls with two custom skins. I have some basic controls, each of them has two different skins, and a control which groups two of these together. I am now wondering how I can implement the skin of the composite control when I want to skin the two embedded controls in the same way, i.e. there should be two skins for the composite controls, and when I apply one of the the embedded controls should also be skinned. Basically, I want to have the skin applied recursively on the control graph.

```
class Control1 extends Control {}
class Control1Skin1 extends SkinBase<Control1> {}
class Control1Skin2 extends SkinBase<Control1> {}

class Control2 extends Control {}
class Control2Skin1 extends SkinBase<Control1> {}
class Control2Skin2 extends SkinBase<Control1> {}

class CompositeControl extend Control {
    private final Control1 ctrl1 = new Control1();
    private final Control2 ctrl2 = new Control2();
}

class CompositeControlSkin1 extends SkinBase<Control1> {}
class CompositeControlSkin2 extends SkinBase<Control1> {}
```

1. Make the controls members of the skin. This leads to code duplication and moves logic into the skin that doesn't belong there.
2. Add accessors to `CompositeControl` to access the embedded controls. This breaks encapsulation.
3. Make the members package private such that the skin can access them and set the skin appropriately. A minor breach in encapsulation, but the skin and control class form a cohesive cluster anyway.
4. Define a custom `CompositeControlSkin` interface which has methods returning the skins for sub-controls. Then, I have to override CompositeControl.setSkin(Skin skin)`to cast the`skin` parameter into the new interface, get the skins and set them. This needs access to the members as in 3, but additionally a down-cast. I think this disqualifies the approach.

I am wondering if there is a better approach in JavaFX, e.g. a composite skin. The documentation about custom skinnable controls I found is a bit sparse, so I would be grateful for any links or hints.

Comment: Since `CompositeControl` is specifically made to encapsulate `Control1` and `Control2`, they are unavoidably tightly-coupled. Additionally, `CompositeControlSkin#` is only applicable for `CompositeControl`, so it may as well be a nested class of `CompositeControl`, thus having access to private members of it, including `ctrl1` and `ctrl2`.

Comment: I think we can agree on that. I am wondering if there is some support in the JavaFX framework for skins of composite controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just make sure you really need additional skins. Skins are only needed if you want controls to look and behave completely different than the default.
Usually, styling the application with CSS is enough.

If you come to the conclusion you really need additional skins, check the following steps:

1. every skinnable custom control should have a specific style class

:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS = "my-control";

    [...]

    public MyControl(){
        getStyleClass().setAll(DEFAULT_STYLE_CLASS);
    }
```

2. identify the controls, which actually need an additional skin. This might not be true for all of your controls (e.g. additional skins for your composite controls might not be necessary)
3. override skins you want to use in a custom CSS:

:

```
.my-control { 
    -fx-skin: "somepackage.skin.MyControlSkin2";
}
```

Please note, that you only need to extend Control and provide skin if you actually want a highly customizable and highly-reusable control.

For application developers, most of the time you can create reusable controls using the fx:root FXML construct. E.g. your composite controls might be candidates for this.

Custom skinnable controls usually don't consist of other controls as this ties the control to a specific look and feel. If you want skinnable composite controls, the nested controls should be in the skin, not in the control.